# Python Curses - Detecting the Backspace Key

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos-high-sierra, python-curses

I'm having a difficult time with detecting the Backspace key using the Curses module. Whenever I press the Backspace key, the character / string returned is '^?', however I'm not able to detect it with:

if str(key) == '^?':

The code below is set up to run

```
import curses

def main(win):
    win.nodelay(True)
    key = ''
    record = ''
    win.clear()
    win.addstr("Key:")
    win.addstr('\n\nRecord:')
    win.addstr(record)
    while True:
        try:
            key = win.getkey()

            if str(key) == '^?':
                # Attempt at detecting the Backspace key
                record = record[:-1]

            elif str(key) == '\n':
                # Attempt at detecting the Enter Key
                record = ''

            else:
                record += str(key)
            win.clear()
            win.addstr("Key:")
            win.addstr(str(key))
            win.addstr('\n\nRecord:')
            win.addstr(record)
            if key == os.linesep:
                break
        except Exception as e:
            # No input
            pass

curses.wrapper(main)
# CTRL+C to close the program
```

Comment: What do `type(key)` and `repr(key)` say when you press backspace?

Comment: type(key): <class 'str'>        repr(key): '\x7f'

Comment: `ord(key)` returns 127 for me when I press backspace, I used this to detect the backspace key.

Answer (score 6):

According to your clarifying comment, backspace in your terminal is neither `'KEY_BACKSPACE'` nor `'\b'` (`'\x08'`).

Since you're using `curses.wrapper()`, which calls `curses.initscr()`, this suggests that something is wrong with either your `terminfo` database (unlikely) or your terminal configuration (more likely).

`getkey() == 'KEY_BACKSPACE'` or `getch() == curses.KEY_BACKSPACE` is supposed to work on any properly-configured system, so you're likely to have problems in other applications too.

The `TERM` environment variable is how the terminal type is communicated to tools which need the functionality beyond basic teletype, so, to fix that, start by checking what the `TERM` environment variable contains in the environment where you're running Python.

```
print(os.environ['TERM'])
```

As a quick hack, you can check all the values it's been observed to take.

```
if key in ('KEY_BACKSPACE', '\b', '\x7f'):
```

Comment: Sorry to anyone who tried the old version of the "quick hack". I had `getkey()` and `getch()` muddled together in my mind.

Comment: By doing `ord(key)`, the integer 127 was returned, so I was able to use that to detect the backspace key.

Comment: For the record, `ord('\x7f') == 127`

Comment: [Isn't 127 supposed to mean the delete key](https://learn.parallax.com/support/reference/ascii-table-0-127) (`curses.ascii.DEL == 127`)?

Answer (score 3):

On my machine, running Python 3.5.2 or 2.7.12, I get `KEY_BACKSPACE` shown as the key when I press backspace, and using

```
if str(key) == 'KEY_BACKSPACE':
```

in place of

```
if str(key) == '^?':
```

results in the backspace key backspacing letters off `record`.

I think it's possible that, on your system, you're getting the actual backspace character. In that case, you might try `'\b'` in place of `'^?'`, as according to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals), that is the string escape for the ASCII backspace character.

Comment: What is do you use

Comment: Neither of those worked for me sadly. I'm using macOS v10.13.1

Comment: `if getch() in [KEY_BACKSPACE, ord('\b')]` works for me

Answer (score 2):

In MacOS, please try this:

```py
    key = w.getch()
    if key == 127:
        print("You've pressed Backspace")
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/curses/textpad.py#L114-L115), the textbox Textbox.edit() method will only backspace a character (e.g. `curses.delch`) when either `curses.ascii.BS` or `curses.ascii.BACKSPACE` are pressed. On MacOS, at least, the `delete` key registers as `curses.ascii.DEL`.

We can pass a custom validate() to overload this functionality such as backspace on DELETE, exist on ESCAPE, and exist on RESIZE:

```py
import curses
import curses.textpad

def get_input(window):
    curses.curs_set(1)
    curses.set_escdelay(1)
    window.addstr(0, 0, "Enter some text:")
    input_box = curses.textpad.Textbox(curses.newwin(1, 40, 1, 0), insert_mode=True)
    
    def validate(ch):

            # exit input with the escape key
            escape = 27
            if ch == escape:
                ch = curses.ascii.BEL # Control-G
            
            # delete the character to the left of the cursor
            elif ch in (curses.KEY_BACKSPACE, curses.ascii.DEL):
                ch = curses.KEY_BACKSPACE
            
            # exit input to resize windows
            elif ch == curses.KEY_RESIZE:
                ch = curses.ascii.BEL # Control-G

            return ch
    
    input_box.edit(validate)
    curses.curs_set(0)
    curses.set_escdelay(1000)
    return input_box.gather().strip()


def main(window):
    curses.noecho()
    curses.cbreak()
    window.keypad(True)
    curses.curs_set(0)

    input_text = get_input(window)

    window.addstr(2, 0, f"You entered: {input_text}")
    window.refresh()
    window.getch()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    curses.wrapper(main)
```